# cancan role strategies strategies comparision / tradeoffs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, authorization, cancan, roles

To create an application that supports authorization in Rails using cancan, it is up to the developer to decide what will be the role method. Now I need to figure out the best for my case - It is the traditional one-role-per-user model.

The methods I found seems to be quite similar from me. I wonder if there is really a technical difference while selecting the role models, or is just a question of preference? If there are techincal differences, what are the trade-offs in selecting one model or another, in special about scaling?

Some possible models I could found:

- Using the gem [rolify](https://github.com/EppO/rolify)
- Using [single table inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701178/rails-single-table-inheritance-or-not-for-applicant-employee-relationship)
- Using a [row in the users table](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Role-Based-Authorization)
- Separated tables for each user type, according to its role
- [Multiple table inheritance](http://techspry.com/ruby_and_rails/multiple-table-inheritance-in-rails-3/)
- [Table with roles](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Separate-Role-Model) and using relationships

Points for articles that compare these approaches on the comments are appreciated, since I couldn't find much material comparing them.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need one role per use, just go with the simplest approach.

1. Add a single string field to user; called "role".
2. Add an array to User to hold the values: `ROLES = %w{System\ Admin Admin Customer Etc}`
3. Add some helper methods to user so you can easily check for a role (i.e. user.admin?)

Role helpers:

```
ROLES.each do |role_name|
  define_method "#{role_name.downcase.tr(" ", "_")}?" do
    role == role_name
  end
end
```

You can easily leverage the more complex options in the future if needed.